# I am getting this (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process) error message

Tags: java, android, java-io

As the title says, I am receiving this error message:

> .........\app\build\intermediates\merged_java_res\debug\out.jar: The
>   process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process.

I am unfortunately very new to Java and using Android Studio. If anyone can help me out that would be much appreciated. If you need further information, let me know.

FYI: I get that the error message is saying that I am attempting to run a process that is being used by another process (even that same process), but I don't understand how to find and fix my issue.

Comment: The problem is the `out.jar` is using by another process. So try to close the Android Studio. I cannot resolve. Try to close all apps and open again.

Answer (score 4):

run  "taskkill /im java.exe /f" in command